# Bad HDD in LVM recovery time at boot

Tags: boot, lvm

My server/desktop started reporting read errors on a HDD in my 16 drive lvm.  The drive is a 2TB WD EARS model.

While I have a backup from April, I'd rather not loose the last month of changes, or the time it will take to rebuild from the backup.

As before, I used the gui to remove the bad drive.   pvmove crashed during the process.   Shortly after that the server crashed.   On bootup it began a repair process.   That was saturday morning, about 3 1/2 days ago.

The server is still showing the bootup messages regarding read errors with a sector number.   The sector number continues to get larger showing progress is being made.  The number is approaching 420 million.     I cant access the server on the network or the local cli/gui desktop.

How long should I let the process run for?

Answer (score 1):

I should have only waited 5 minutes and saved myself four days of waiting.

At sector 675M I rebooted and it started back at the beginning, so I pulled the drive, rebooted, crashed, pulled all drives except the boot drive, then got my desktop back.   Eventually I got the computer to boot with all but the bad drive attached, Skipping the disk check and Cancelling the wait for the bad lv mount.

Now one 8T ext4 fs out of the 24T vg is back but the 14T ext4 lv appears beyond repair.  the lvm gui tool crashes when launched, something to do with the pvmove0 segment I cant seem to get rid of.